# Unity WebGL build throws "TypeError: dbg is undefined"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, local-storage, unity-webgl

I was messing around trying to save data for a Unity application built for the web in the `Application.persistentDataPath`. It was appearing to save, but failing to load.

That is, my application would attempt to save and not throw any errors (which I was catching and displaying internally). Although it was not confirming a *success* either (other notifications display, but neither the confirmed-failure or confirmed-success for saving). Then when loading it would throw a notification for being unable to load the saved data, but have no message/error reason.

Inserting some additional attempts to isolate what was going wrong, suddenly it was failing to start, throwing a `TypeError: dbg is undefined` which appears to be originating in Unity's export code (i.e. nothing I have control over).

In trying to clear out an leftover data from partial saves, etc. (by using the Firefox developer tools to inspect and modify the indexDB local storage) I have appeared to inadvertently deleted some value that Unity uses and now when I try to run my application (**ANY AND ALL** Unity webgl applications run from *any website or directory* are failing for me!) Unity tells me that it was unable to allocate enough memory (and no matter what I do in the publish settings, I cannot make this error go away).

After restarting my machine the errors went away for a few builds, then returned.

Comment: I am a bit confuse....This problem happens when you try to save data?

Comment: @Programmer no, the `TypeError: dbg is undefined` error occurs *before* the loading screen. LOOOOONG before my own code. It's just that in messing around with save/load code did the error appear.

Comment: Ok.If you remove the save/load code, does the error appear? If yes, please post the save.load code. I want to try it on my side to see if I can replciate this

Comment: @Programmer No, removing the code does not make the error change (i.e. error shows up -> removing save/load code entirely -> error still shows up).